# Is there any way to filter JSON using amp html

Tags: html, amp-html

I know that there is a planned feature upgrade to create a custom amp-filter tag
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9113

I was wondering if there was any workaround to doing client-side filtering of json using amp html?

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have at the moment is combining amp-list and amp-bind. Use amp-bind to dynamically change the amp-list src attribute based on the selected filter. The actual filtering still needs to happen server-side. Here is a sample implementation:  https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/product_browse_page/preview/.